# convert jsonb column value to multiple columns in PostgreSQL

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

lets say i have a table in PostgreSQL with the following columns:

```
CREATE TABLE sample
(
id int,
jsonb jsonb,
date date
)
```

and i inserted this two rows:

```
INSERT INTO sample
(id,jsonb,date)
VALUES
(1, '{"a":"a","b":"b"}', '2014/01/06'),
(2, '{"a":"a","b":"b"}', '2014/01/06')
```

i want to convert the above rows into this(doing a select in PostgreSQL):

```
1,"a","b",'2014/01/06'
2,"a","b",'2014/01/06'
```

to call in php `json_encode(rows from sample)`

and get something like this:

```
[{"id":1,"a":"a","b":"b","date":"2014/01/06"},
{"id":2,"a":"a","b":"b","date":"2014/01/06"}]
```

but now if i call in php `json_encode(rows from sample)` i get this:

```
[{"id":1,"jsonb":"{"a":"a","b":"b"}","date":"2014/01/06"},
{"id":2,"jsonb":"{"a":"a","b":"b"}","date":"2014/01/06"}]
```

hope someone can help me to handle that, thanks to everyone

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is simple in 9.4 (used LATERAL join and jsonb functions):

```
    postgres=# SELECT * 
                  FROM sample, jsonb_to_record(jsonb, true) AS x(a text, b text);
     id |            jsonb             |    date     |  a   |   b    
    ----+------------------------------+-------------+------+--------
      1 | {"a": "a", "b": "b"}         | 2014-01-06  | a    | b
      2 | {"a": "a", "b": "b"}         | 2014-01-06  | a    | b
      3 | {"a": "Ahoj", "b": "Nazdar"} | 2014-01-06  | Ahoj | Nazdar
    (3 rows)
```

exact result:

```
postgres=# SELECT id, a, b, date 
               FROM sample, jsonb_to_record(jsonb, true) AS x(a text, b text);
 id |  a   |   b    |    date    
----+------+--------+------------
  1 | a    | b      | 2014-01-06
  2 | a    | b      | 2014-01-06
  3 | Ahoj | Nazdar | 2014-01-06
(3 rows)
```

Comment: Awesome Pavel, that's what i was looking for, thanks a lot for your help, i'm working with modular angularjs application, feel free to ask me whenever you want, maybe i can help you one day, cheers!

Comment: @AlejandroSanchez :) with pleasure

Comment: Hi Pavel, hope you can help me a little again, do you know how to add a "Where" clause to the code you shared with me, i could do it but only with a subquery, and i dont know if its the best way to do it. Thanks in advance

Comment: @AlejandroSanchez subqueries in PostgreSQL are ok, don't afraid about them

Comment: The `jsonb_to_record` function has changed in the last four years, now it is `jsonb_to_record(jsonb)` with no second argument.